# Cannot access git (atlassian stash) repository from reviewboard

Tags: git, ssh, review-board, bitbucket-server

I am setting up a reviewboard instance for my git (stash) repository, but I am having problems.

I set up my path (using the clone url) and my repository type is git, but I am getting this error:     [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname.

Now I though I was having a dns problem, but I am actually able to clone the repository manually by using my username or the www-data (apache user of my box).

Checking the reviewboard logs I see this:

```
2013-10-27 11:51:48,992 - DEBUG -  - GitTool: Attempting ssh connection with host: STASH_HOST, username: MY_USERNAME
2013-10-27 11:51:49,106 - DEBUG -  - starting thread (client mode): 0x5c0b7090L
2013-10-27 11:51:49,217 - INFO -  - Connected (version 2.0, client SSHD-CORE-0.7.0-ATLASSIAN-M3)
2013-10-27 11:51:49,217 - DEBUG -  - kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc'] server encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-md5-96', 'hmac-sha1-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-md5-96', 'hmac-sha1-96'] client compress:['none'] server compress:['none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
2013-10-27 11:51:49,218 - DEBUG -  - Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-cbc, remote=aes128-cbc
2013-10-27 11:51:49,218 - DEBUG -  - using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-cbc, remote aes128-cbc; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
2013-10-27 11:51:49,472 - DEBUG -  - Switch to new keys ...
2013-10-27 11:51:49,774 - DEBUG -  - EOF in transport thread
```

I *think* this might happen because reviewboard does not use the right ssh keys? I have generated them manually and through reviewboard (and set on my stash server), but it didn't help. As I said before if I clone it manually it works fine.

Any ideas? The reviewboard version is 1.7.16

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I cloned the repository manually, had reviewboard pointing to it, and then had a cron job to constantly pull all the changes from origin.

It looks like it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

this message indicates that review board user can't clone your git repo.

login as review-user

try git clone ssh://gitadmin@example.com/something.git

if this fails - please add / append your public keys pair in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys at gitadmin@example.com

Comment: what do you mean by review-user? I actually tried to do what you described using www-data which is the apache user and I can clone it manually, but reviewboard always returns the same error message. Are you talking about another system user? I am not sure why reviewboard is not using the right ssh keys (which are all in the git server)

Comment: please examine  ~/.ssh/config of www-data